# How to strip Ruby string of all characters that are not word characters?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I strip a string in Ruby of all characters that aren't word characters (a-z, any digit), replacing them with a blank?

For instance, for the string "not-using-social-media" I want to strip this to "not using social media"

For the string "16 Surprising Small Business Statistics (Infographic)", I want to strip this to "16 Surprising Small Business Statistics Infographic"

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" We expect you to show some effort, either in having searched for solutions with explanations why those don't work, or showing the code you wrote toward solving the problem. You're asking us to put time into helping you, so it's reasonable we ask the same of you.

Comment: @theTinMan with regex this requirement is very difficult to fulfill... Even good rules should have exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

This does not use a regex. It replaces everything which is *not* in "a-zA-Z0-9 " with a space, then squeezes runs of spaces to one space and removes trailing and tailing whitespace.

```
str = "not-using-social-media 16 Surprising Small Business Statistics (Infographic)"
p str.tr("^a-zA-Z0-9 ", " ").squeeze(" ").strip
#=>"not using social media 16 Surprising Small Business Statistics Infographic"
```

Comment: +1 for using `tr` and another +1 for `squeeze`. Oh. SO won't let me do two +1. You've been cheated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do either:

```
phrase = '16 Surprising Small Business Statistics (Infographic)'

p phrase.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/, ' ').strip
#=> "16 Surprising Small Business Statistics Infographic"

p phrase.gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]+/, ' ').strip
#=> "16 Surprising Small Business Statistics Infographic"
```

A couple of notes:

- The `+` is added so that consecutive non-alphanumeric characters are replaced with a single space.
- The `.strip` is added on the assumption you do not want the leading/trailing spaces created.
- The regex does not use `\w` since that would also include underscores.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is simply using `delete('^')`.
It deletes everything except for what comes after `^`.

```
a='hello-world+'

a.delete('^A-Za-z')  #=> 'helloworld'

a='Hello +World'

a.delete('^A-Za-z ') #=> 'Hello World'

a='01234 ABC'
a.delete('^0-9') #=> '01234'
```

Comment: "Simplest" is debatable, but this is *definitely* incorrect. He doesn't want to strip the characters out, he wants to replace them with a space, and your solution makes this impossible. Once he's deleted the characters, he has no means of telling where they were in order to reinsert a space.

Comment: Just used your fourth example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend  - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

This is the bracket expression you'll want - /[[:alpha:]]/